# Is it okay to run my system off a flash drive?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, live-usb, flash-memory, persistence

I've been running my main system off a Linux persistent LiveCD flash drive for a couple months. The drive has a 2 GiB fat32 boot partition, and a 12.91 GiB ext2 casper-rw partition. I'm running Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon 64-bit, and it's meeting all my (minimal) performance needs.

Is this okay for my flash drive and for my computer? My RAM hovers around 40%–65% usage, and never needs swap (no thrashing), and it seems pretty fast for the most part.

What, if anything, do I need to worry about here?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest concern is probably [memory wear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Memory_wear) which causes flash memory to have much fewer writes than magnetic media before failing.

Of course, standard hard drives fail also, so just ensure that you have backups suitable to the needs of whatever you are doing with the machine.

Comment: That's what I figured—do you know how much of an impact this is? How long will it take my drive to fail?